# Migrating Repo from Gitlab to Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, gitlab, version-control-migration

I am migrating repositories (.Net, Angular) from `GitLab` to `Azure DevOps`. Can't find much documentation on the implications of this migration.

My questions are:

1. Do all remote branches gets migrated? With all commits and comments?
2. Does Azure DevOps support sub-folder type repository structure?

Any precautions/best practices I may have to consider.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Do you mean to git sub-modules?

Comment: No. a repository has multiple folders inside.

Comment: See my answer below (check the link there, is a good tutorial how to import).

Comment: Does Azure also import the Merge Request and issue details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, when you [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts) a Git repository from GitLab (or any Git server) to Azure DevOps, all the branches and folders will be imported with all the history (commits).